# How to set the same exponent of 10 in in scientific notation for column in pgfplotstable?

Tags: pgfplotstable, pgfkeys

I need all the numbers in the first column to have the same exponent of ten, say `10^{-2}`. 
It would be nice if the multiplier was placed not near the number, but in the header of the table.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableread[]{
    X       Y    Xerror Yerror  Y2
    0       0    0       0     0
    0.022   0.4  0.005   0.1   0.66
    0.038   0.8  0.005   0.1   1.14
    0.058   1.2  0.005   0.1   1.74
    0.09    1.6  0.005   0.1   2.7
    0.101   2    0.005   0.1   3.03
    0.123   2.4  0.005   0.1   3.69
    0.130   2.8  0.005   0.1   3.9
}\datatable

\begin{document}

    \pgfplotstableset{
    columns={X,Y,Xerror,Yerror},
    columns/X/.style={
        column name={$x$, \si{\meter}},
        /pgf/number format/.cd, sci, sci zerofill, relative*={-3}
    },
    columns/Y/.style={
        column name={$F_\mathbf{elast}$, \si{\newton}},
        /pgf/number format/.cd, fixed, fixed zerofill,
    },
    columns/Xerror/.style={
        column name={$\Delta x$, \si{\meter}},
        /pgf/number format/.cd, relative*={-2}
    },
    columns/Yerror/.style={
        column name={$\Delta F_\mathbf{elast}$, \si{\newton}},
    },
    every head row/.style={
        before row={\toprule},
        after row={\midrule}
    },
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
}
\pgfplotstabletypeset{\datatable}

\end{document}
```

**Desired result should looks like in picture below**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `relative*`, you can use `multiply by` to scale the values. Then you just have to change the `column name` to contain the power of 10.

Also, there is no need to use `/pgf/number format/.cd`, `pgfplotstable` understands, that you want set the number format.

The code:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableread[]{
    X       Y    Xerror Yerror  Y2
    0       0    0       0     0
    0.022   0.4  0.005   0.1   0.66
    0.038   0.8  0.005   0.1   1.14
    0.058   1.2  0.005   0.1   1.74
    0.09    1.6  0.005   0.1   2.7
    0.101   2    0.005   0.1   3.03
    0.123   2.4  0.005   0.1   3.69
    0.130   2.8  0.005   0.1   3.9
}\datatable

\begin{document}

    \pgfplotstableset{
    columns={X,Y,Xerror,Yerror},
    columns/X/.style={
        column name={$x$, \SI{e-2}{\meter}},
        multiply by=100,
        fixed, fixed zerofill,
    },
    columns/Y/.style={
        column name={$F_\mathbf{elast}$, \si{\newton}},
        fixed, fixed zerofill,
    },
    columns/Xerror/.style={
        column name={$\Delta x$, \SI{e-3}{\meter}},
        multiply by=1000
    },
    columns/Yerror/.style={
        column name={$\Delta F_\mathbf{elast}$, \si{\newton}},
    },
    every head row/.style={
        before row={\toprule},
        after row={\midrule}
    },
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
}
\pgfplotstabletypeset{\datatable}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]